# How can I properly align images (with text) with HTML and CSS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to set up a website where I intend to have some responsive features which allow it to be functional even with smartphones, tablets, etc.
I'll share the relevant code so it's easier to get to the point:

> HTML

```
    /* First Problem - Images won't be in the centre of the screen (they tend to the right side) */
    <ul class="slices">
        <li><img src="Content/Media/home_img_part1.jpg" /></li>
        <li><img src="Content/Media/home_img_part2.jpg" /></li>
        <li><img src="Content/Media/home_img_part3.jpg" /></li>
        <li><img src="Content/Media/home_img_part4.jpg" /></li>
    </ul>

    /* Second Problem - Text doesn't keep in the same line as the *img* element */
    <article>
        <img src="https://static.wixstatic.com/media/64fcdd_d2442874c5254a63b4d5f721967b88e2.png/v1/fill/w_47,h_40,al_c,usm_0.66_1.00_0.01/64fcdd_d2442874c5254a63b4d5f721967b88e2.png" />
        <h4>"Aquilo que os nosso clientes de facto querem não é apenas o conhecimento, mas a certeza de que o sabemos aplicar"</h4>
        <p><h4 class="bold">NC TI Consultant  - DNR</h4></p>
    </article>
    <article>
        <img src="https://static.wixstatic.com/media/64fcdd_d2442874c5254a63b4d5f721967b88e2.png/v1/fill/w_47,h_40,al_c,usm_0.66_1.00_0.01/64fcdd_d2442874c5254a63b4d5f721967b88e2.png" />
        <h4>"A DNR é uma equipa jovem e dinâmica, sempre pronta a apresentar novas soluções e estratégias que nos facilitam o  processo de trabalho. Tornando-o ágil e produtivo A nossa relação baseia-se  sobretudo numa grande transparência e ajuda mútua."</h4>
        <p><h4 class="bold">Engº Ricardo Cabral - Totallink</h4></p>
    </article>
```

> CSS

```
    img {
        text-align: center;
        max-width: 100%;
        height: auto;
        width: auto;
    }

    nav ul li {
        display: inline-block;
        float: left;
        padding: 10px;
    }

    ul.slices li {
        display: inline-block;
        float: left;
        text-align: center;
        margin: 40px 0 0 10px;
    }

    article {
        float: left;
        margin: 0 auto;
        width: 42%;
        height: auto;
        padding: 4%;
        text-align: justify;
    }
```

Right now, I've got 2 problems:

1. The 4 images in the ***ul.slices li*** don't align horizontally in the centre of the browser
2. On each article, the **img** elements and the corresponding text won't align horizontally

Should I solve this by adding something like ***div*** elements or is my CSS incorrect?
Thanks in advance,
Granvic

```css
* {
            margin: 0;
            border: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }

        body {
            background: #f0f0f0;
            font: 14px/20px Calibri;
            color: #555;
            margin: 0;
        }

        p {
            padding: 1%;
        }

        img {
            text-align: center;
            max-width: 100%;
            height: auto;
            width: auto;
        }

        a {
            color: #000;
            text-decoration: none;
        }

            a:hover {
                color: #000;
                font-weight: bold;
            }

        header {
            background-color: #FFF;
            width: 100%;
            height: 150px;
            /*position: fixed;*/
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            z-index: 100;
            opacity: 0.90;
        }

        #logo {
            margin: 10px;
            float: left;
            width: 220px;
            height: 140px;
            background: url(https://static.wixstatic.com/media/64fcdd_b1431dbdfce24a69864ca9c381d36c5a.png/v1/fill/w_353,h_218,al_c,usm_0.66_1.00_0.01/64fcdd_b1431dbdfce24a69864ca9c381d36c5a.png) no-repeat center;
        }

        nav {
            float: right;
            padding: 90px 20px 20px 0;
        }

        #menu-icon {
            /*visibility: hidden;*/
            display: none;
            width: 40px;
            height: 40px;
            background: url(http://cdn.mysitemyway.com/etc-mysitemyway/icons/legacy-previews/icons/matte-grey-square-icons-media/119425-matte-grey-square-icon-media-media2-arrow-down.png) center;
            background-size: cover;
        }

        a:hover#menu-icon {
            border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0;
        }

        ul {
            list-style: none;
        }

        nav ul li {
            display: inline-block;
            float: left;
            padding: 10px;
        }

        .current {
            color: red;
            text-decoration: underline;
            font-weight: bolder;
        }
        /* TREAT THIS */
        ul.slices li {
            display: inline-block;
            float: left;
            text-align: center;
            margin: 40px 0 0 10px;
        }

        .clear {
            clear: both;
        }

        section {
            width: 46%;
            float: left;
            margin: 2% 2%;
            text-align: center;
        }

        article {
            float: left;
            margin: 0 auto;
            width: 42%;
            height: auto;
            padding: 4%;
            text-align: justify;
        }

            article h4 {
                font-weight: normal;
                font-style: italic;
            }

                article h4.bold {
                    float: right;
                    font-weight: bold;
                    font-style: italic;
                }

        footer {
            background: #f0f0f0;
            width: 100%;
            overflow: hidden;
            opacity: 0.90;
        }

            footer p, footer h3 {
                color: #000;
            }

                footer p a {
                    color: #000;
                    text-decoration: none;
                }

        ul.social li {
            display: inline;
        }

            ul.social li img {
                height: 30px;
            }
        /*------------------------------- MEDIA -------------------------------*/
        @media screen and (max-width: 478px) {
            body {
                position: absolute;
            }
        }

        @media screen and (max-width: 740px) {
            header {
                position: absolute;
            }

            #menu-icon {
                display: inline-block;
            }

            nav ul, nav:active ul {
                display: none;
                position: absolute;
                padding: 20px;
                background: #f0f0f0;
                border: 1px solid #FFF;
                right: 20px;
                top: 60px;
                width: 50%;
                border-radius: 2px 0 2px 2px;
            }

            nav li {
                text-align: center;
                width: 100%;
                padding: 10px 0;
                margin: 0;
            }

            nav:hover ul {
                display: block;
            }

            section {
                float: left;
                width: 100%;
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
            }

            article {
                float: left;
                width: 100%;
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
            }
        }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>DNR Improving Solutions</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=divice-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <style type="text/css">
        
    </style>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <a href="#" id="logo"></a>
        <nav>
            <a href="#" id="menu-icon"></a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#" class="current">Início</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">DNR</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">PHC</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Soluções</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Notícias</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Loja e Carrinho</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contacto</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>
    <ul class="slices">
        <li><img src="Content/Media/home_img_part1.jpg" /></li>
        <li><img src="Content/Media/home_img_part2.jpg" /></li>
        <li><img src="Content/Media/home_img_part3.jpg" /></li>
        <li><img src="Content/Media/home_img_part4.jpg" /></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="clear"></div>
    <article>
        <img src="Content/Media/double_right_arrow.png" />
        <h4>"Aquilo que os nosso clientes de facto querem não é apenas o conhecimento, mas a certeza de que o sabemos aplicar"</h4>
        <p><h4 class="bold">NC TI Consultant  - DNR</h4></p>
    </article>
    <article>
        <img src="Content/Media/double_right_arrow.png" />
        <h4>"A DNR é uma equipa jovem e dinâmica, sempre pronta a apresentar novas soluções e estratégias que nos facilitam o  processo de trabalho. Tornando-o ágil e produtivo A nossa relação baseia-se  sobretudo numa grande transparência e ajuda mútua."</h4>
        <p><h4 class="bold">Engº Ricardo Cabral - Totallink</h4></p>
    </article>
    <footer>
        <section>
            <img src="Content/Media/dnr_footer_logo.png" />
            <h5>&copy;2016 DNRwebdesign</h5>
        </section>
        <section>
            <h3>Newsletter DNR</h3>
            <input type="text" id="email" placeholder="Email" />
            <p><button id="submit">Assine Agora</button></p>
            <ul class="social">
                <li><a href="http://www.dnris.com/feed.xml" target="_self"><img src="Content/Media/rss_feed_logo.png" /></a></li>
                <li><a href="https://www.facebook.com/pages/DNR/406091066242029?view_public_for=406091066242029" target="_blank"><img src="Content/Media/facebook_logo.png" /></a></li>
                <li><a href="https://twitter.com/dnrimprovingsol" target="_blank"><img src="Content/Media/twitter_logo.png" /></a></li>
                <li><a href="https://plus.google.com/u/0/117524251491512615717/posts" target="_blank"><img src="Content/Media/google_plus_logo.png" /></a></li>
            </ul>
            <p>DNR - Todos os direitos reservados</p>
        </section>
    </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: We don't need the **whole** page, just enough to demo this issue. Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Thanks for the recommendations and respective info! I shortened by question and added a code snippet.

Answer (score 1):

1. You should remove the margin to the bottom for the logo because that makes the whole `ul` move to the right since the logo is too high. Then you should also remove the floating for the `ul.slices li` elements since you display them as `inline-blocks` and therefore no float is required. Also add `text-align:center` to the `ul` surrounding your four images. Once you have done that the four images will be centered.
2. Simply add `text-align:center` to the `articles` and add `text-align:justify` to the `h4` elements.

*Please click on "Full Page" below to see the changes I made (resize window until > 740px).*

PS: to make the four images not move behind the header on small devices you would need to either give a padding to the body or set the header back to `position:relative` inside your media queries.

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    border: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
body {
    background: #f0f0f0;
    font: 14px/20px Calibri;
    color: #555;
    margin: 0;
}
p {
    padding: 1%;
}
img {
    text-align: center;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    width: auto;
}
a {
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
}
a:hover {
    color: #000;
    font-weight: bold;
}
header {
    background-color: #FFF;
    width: 100%;
    height: 150px;
    /*position: fixed;*/
    
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 100;
    opacity: 0.90;
}
#logo {
    margin-right: 10px;
    float: left;
    width: 220px;
    height: 140px;
    background: url(https://static.wixstatic.com/media/64fcdd_b1431dbdfce24a69864ca9c381d36c5a.png/v1/fill/w_353,h_218,al_c,usm_0.66_1.00_0.01/64fcdd_b1431dbdfce24a69864ca9c381d36c5a.png) no-repeat center;
}
nav {
    float: right;
    padding: 90px 20px 20px 0;
}
#menu-icon {
    /*visibility: hidden;*/
    
    display: none;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    background: url("http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/graphicloads/100-flat/128/settings-icon.png") center;
    background-size: cover;
}
a:hover#menu-icon {
    border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0;
}
ul {
    list-style: none;
}
nav ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px;
}
.current {
    color: red;
    text-decoration: underline;
    font-weight: bolder;
}
/* TREAT THIS */

ul.slices {
    text-align: center;
}
ul.slices li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 40px 0 0 10px;
}
.clear {
    clear: both;
}
section {
    width: 46%;
    float: left;
    margin: 2% 2%;
    text-align: center;
}
article {
    float: left;
    margin: 55px auto;
    width: 42%;
    height: auto;
    padding: 4%;
    text-align: center;
}
article h4 {
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: italic;
    text-align:justify;
}
article img
{
    float:left;
    margin-right:15px;
}
article h4.bold {
    float: right;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-style: italic;
}
footer {
    background: #f0f0f0;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    opacity: 0.90;
}
footer p,
footer h3 {
    color: #000;
}
footer p a {
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
}
ul.social li {
    display: inline;
}
ul.social li img {
    height: 30px;
}
/*------------------------------- MEDIA -------------------------------*/

@media screen and (max-width: 478px) {
    body {
        position: absolute;
    }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 740px) {
    header {
        position: absolute;
    }
    #menu-icon {
        display: inline-block;
    }
    nav ul,
    nav:active ul {
        display: none;
        position: absolute;
        padding: 20px;
        background: #f0f0f0;
        border: 1px solid #FFF;
        right: 20px;
        top: 60px;
        width: 50%;
        border-radius: 2px 0 2px 2px;
    }
    nav li {
        text-align: center;
        width: 100%;
        padding: 10px 0;
        margin: 0;
    }
    nav:hover ul {
        display: block;
    }
    section {
        float: left;
        width: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }
    article {
        float: left;
        width: 100%;
        margin: 15px 0;
        padding: 0;
    }
}
```

```html
<header>
    <a href="#" id="logo"></a>
    <nav>
        <a href="#" id="menu-icon"></a>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="#" class="current">Início</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">DNR</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">PHC</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Soluções</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Notícias</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Loja e Carrinho</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Contacto</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</header>
<ul class="slices">
    <li>
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100" />
    </li>
    <li>
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100" />
    </li>
    <li>
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100" />
    </li>
    <li>
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100" />
    </li>
</ul>
<div class="clear"></div>
<article>
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/100" />
    <h4>"Aquilo que os nosso clientes de facto querem não é apenas o conhecimento, mas a certeza de que o sabemos aplicar"</h4>
    <h4 class="bold">NC TI Consultant  - DNR</h4>
</article>
<article>
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/100" />
    <h4>"A DNR é uma equipa jovem e dinâmica, sempre pronta a apresentar novas soluções e estratégias que nos facilitam o  processo de trabalho. Tornando-o ágil e produtivo A nossa relação baseia-se  sobretudo numa grande transparência e ajuda mútua."</h4>
    <h4 class="bold">Engº Ricardo Cabral - Totallink</h4>
</article>
<footer>
    <section>
        <img src="Content/Media/dnr_footer_logo.png" />
        <h5>&copy;2016 DNRwebdesign</h5>
    </section>
    <section>
        <h3>Newsletter DNR</h3>
        <input type="text" id="email" placeholder="Email" />
        <p>
            <button id="submit">Assine Agora</button>
        </p>
        <ul class="social">
            <li>
                <a href="#" target="_self">
                    <img src="Content/Media/rss_feed_logo.png" />
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#" target="_blank">
                    <img src="Content/Media/facebook_logo.png" />
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#" target="_blank">
                    <img src="Content/Media/twitter_logo.png" />
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#" target="_blank">
                    <img src="Content/Media/google_plus_logo.png" />
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <p>DNR - Todos os direitos reservados</p>
    </section>
</footer>
```

Comment: Wow, this solved my first problem! For that, thanks a lot. Now I'd like to align horizontally the image and text of each article, just the _**p**_ would be under the text itself.

Comment: But that's the way it is right now, isn't it? The `p` right below the image and the image centered above the text.

Comment: Yes, it is that way, but I want the _**img**_ element to be on the left of the _**p**_ element, not above it, just like both were in the same row.

Comment: Please see my updated answer. You would need to float the images left so that the text starts on the right side of the images.